# Rewrite rule not working in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, xampp

Hi this is the RewriteRule that i am trying to apply

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^coloragon/([^/]*)\.html$ /coloragon/pair_pixel_filter.php?type=$1 [L]
```

for the following URL

```
http://localhost/coloragon/pair_pixel_filter.php?type=0
```

but it do not seem to work at all. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You do understand you need to access `http://localhost/0.html` to get it to show you the content of `http://localhost/coloragon/pair_pixel_filter.php?type=0` with you current rule, right?

Comment: @prix:Yes mate i do understand that, for start this was a follow up question that how can i make it somewhat like coloragon/0.html, But for the moment i see no change at all.

Comment: Are you placing the `.htaccess` inside the `coloragon` or on the `root` folder?

Comment: @Prix: i guess it will be somewhat like this RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^coloragon/([^/]*)\.html$ /coloragon/pair_pixel_filter.php?type=$1 [L]
Yes i am placing it within coloragon folder which is for the time root folder of the project

Comment: root folder is whatever leads you to `http://localhost/` not `http://localhost/coloragon`, so if you're placing it on the root folder you will need the `coloragon/` at your rule like you above mentioned.

Comment: @Prix: ok so i guess my above said re write is much closer, but i still see no difference

Comment: Well I don't know what is XAMPP's default root folder, but if you check the apache config it will be defined at the `DocumentRoot` directive.

Comment: @Prix: Any reason that come to your mind?

Comment: Like I early mentioned you have the wrong rule for the place your `.htaccess` is located *or a secondary `.htaccess` nullifying the first one.*